# Hacked printer or PC - stackoverflowin/sthack

Tags: security

My wifi printer has just printed this after printing a pdf:

stackoverflowin/sthack the hacker god has returned - sthack@protonmail.com - h

My PC **and/or** printer is compromised?

Comment: We have some clients complaining about this too. Our guess, the printer is publicated (in your firewall/modem) to receive packets/printers from any IP on the internet.

Comment: Don't think you are trolling because I found [this](http://pastebin.com/2FDzA38q) but don't have an answer either. Quite feels like your printer is bugged

Comment: Did you happen to have any ports directed at your printer open in your firewall/router? Was ePrint on?
What brand printer was this? Model could help too. How did you know it was a pdf? Please answer OP and we might be able to help a bit more. Thanks

Comment: I've encountered the same message on a printer with a public IP, which I'm assuming is the issue… The printer is an HP Color LaserJet and the obvious question is whether it's possible to limit access to let's say a range of IPs because I doubt I'll able to build a proper network infrastructure (work).

Comment: See here https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/a-hacker-just-pwned-over-150-000-printers-left-exposed-online/

Comment: @YisroelTech, can you post as an answer? Thanks

Comment: It is more complicated than a simple answer. A read through the Bleeping Computer article should give you some answers.

Comment: @YisroelTech Oddly enough that article lists this question in one of the first paragraphs.